# Mobile Backend handle continuous queries in background

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm using Mobile Backend Starter in my app, and I'm able to continuously receive data using this code:

```
CloudCallbackHandler<List<CloudEntity>> handler = new CloudCallbackHandler<List<CloudEntity>>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(List<CloudEntity> results) {
            Logger.log(MainActivity.this, "onComplete");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(IOException e) {
            Logger.log(MainActivity.this, e);
        }
    };

    CloudQuery cq = new CloudQuery("Test");
    cq.setLimit(50);
    cq.setSort(CloudEntity.PROP_UPDATED_AT, Order.DESC);
    cq.setScope(Scope.FUTURE_AND_PAST);
    getCloudBackend().list(cq, handler);
```

This all works fine when my app is active, but I want to use this to notify the user new data is available, when the app is *not* active.

When I close the app (by pressing back, not home), and I force a message to my device, I get the following error:

```
07-04 18:30:23.084: I/CloudBackend(31368): error: 
07-04 18:30:23.084: I/CloudBackend(31368): com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException
07-04 18:30:23.084: I/CloudBackend(31368):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:222)
07-04 18:30:23.084: I/CloudBackend(31368):  at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:836)
07-04 18:30:23.084: I/CloudBackend(31368):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:412)
07-04 18:30:23.084: I/CloudBackend(31368):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:345)
07-04 18:30:23.084: I/CloudBackend(31368):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:463)
07-04 18:30:23.084: I/CloudBackend(31368):  at com.myapp.cloudbackend.CloudBackend.list(CloudBackend.java:340)
07-04 18:30:23.084: I/CloudBackend(31368):  at com.myapp.cloudbackend.CloudBackendAsync.access$8(CloudBackendAsync.java:1)
07-04 18:30:23.084: I/CloudBackend(31368):  at com.myapp.cloudbackend.CloudBackendAsync$9.callBackend(CloudBackendAsync.java:283)
07-04 18:30:23.084: I/CloudBackend(31368):  at com.myapp.cloudbackend.CloudBackendAsync$9.callBackend(CloudBackendAsync.java:1)
07-04 18:30:23.084: I/CloudBackend(31368):  at com.myapp.cloudbackend.CloudBackendAsync$BackendCaller.run(CloudBackendAsync.java:429)
07-04 18:30:23.084: I/CloudBackend(31368): Caused by: com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: AppDownloadRequired
07-04 18:30:23.084: I/CloudBackend(31368):  at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
07-04 18:30:23.084: I/CloudBackend(31368):  at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
07-04 18:30:23.084: I/CloudBackend(31368):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:192)
07-04 18:30:23.084: I/CloudBackend(31368):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:217)
07-04 18:30:23.084: I/CloudBackend(31368):  ... 9 more
```

How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have two distinct problems.

Let's talk about how to notify the user new data is available, when the app is not active, actually, you don't have to implement another intent service, there is already one up and running in the CloudBackendAndroidClientSample project, all you have to do is show up a notification to the user as soon as you get new message. This can easily be done by adding the following method to the GCMIntentService class:

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
...
//add this method
public void showNotification(Context context, int id, String title, String message){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, GuestbookActivity.class);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context.getApplicationContext())
            .setTicker(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOngoing(false)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setLights(0xFFFF0000, 500, 500); //setLights (int argb, int onMs, int offMs)
    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();

    // show it in the notification list
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
    Log.d(TAG, "notification should be shown");
}
...
//And simply call that function in your onMessage callback
@Override
public void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // decode subId in the message
    String subId = intent.getStringExtra(GCM_KEY_SUBID);
    Log.i(Consts.TAG, "onMessage: subId: " + subId);
    String[] tokens = subId.split(":");
    String typeId = tokens[1];

    // dispatch message
    if (GCM_TYPEID_QUERY.equals(typeId)) {
        CloudBackendAsync.handleQueryMessage(tokens[2]);
        Log.e(TAG, "update notif");
        //call the fonction to show up your notification here
        showNotification(context, 1, getString(R.string.app_name), "new messages!");
    }
}
...
}
```

Now Let's talk about the error you got, this is mainly because you have enabled "Secured by Client IDs" option in your Mobile Backend Starter server config page without specifying a web_client_id in both : server config page and android app consts file. The current CloudBackendAndroidClientSample does not properly handle the lake of Oauth authorization So everytime you start the app again and it need to access the server, a UserRecoverableAuthIOException is thrown but instead of showing you the OAuth consent dialog the sample app does actually nothing.
So in order to solve this problem, you can either:

1. (Preferred) Make sure you declared and use the same web client id in your app and in your server config as described in this [google I/O video around 19'](http://youtu.be/v5u_Owtbfew?t=18m47s)
2. (Silly) Change the sample code to show the Oauth consent dialog whenever the exception occur, so that the user can grant access your app to your server, which is silly from a User Experience perspective in that case, you can take a look a the google drive tutorial sample code on [github](https://github.com/alberovalley/Google-Drive-Tutorial/blob/master/src/com/alberovalley/gdrivetutorial/MainActivity.java). 
   In CloudBackendAndroidClientSample the exception is catched in CloudBackendAsync around line 430

   ```
   private abstract class BackendCaller<PARAM, RESULT> extends Thread {  
   ...

   @Override
   public void run() {
   ...

      try{
         r = callBackend(param);
      } 
      catch (IOException e) {
         Log.i(Consts.TAG, "error: ", e);
         //The UserRecoverableAuthIOException is only logged here, a OAuth Consent Dialog should be opened to grant access to the server.
         ie = e;
      }

      //So you should change this catch by something like the following. 
      //Of course you will need an activity context to be able to call startActivityForResult, that is why I said you will need a little bit of refactoring.
      catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
         startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
      }
   ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I have not played with the Mobile Backend Starter but your question sounds like you would like to implement a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) and use the cloud backend inside the service. Thus, you can establish a communication while your app is not active. Here's e a [good tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html).

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best thing to use is either a Service http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html or the GCM library http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html from Google. It can send push notifications to your Android device, which can force your device to do something. For synchronize data.

Answer (score 0):

That might be in Activity so when you close your application Application Manager will destroy it. So best thing is to use a Service. You can take data from Service in OnServiceConnected method. Also you can fire notification from Services too!